# Get highest numeric value from an array using liquid

Tags: handlebars.js, liquid, liquid-layout

I need help in liquid code. I am getting some values inside an array like:
tags: [teacher, student, test_123, test_12345, unregistered]
In my scenario I just need highest numeric value 12345 which is available as string as test_12345 in the above array. And I need to get this done through liquid code. Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: what have you tried so far ? can you post your current code.

Comment: {% assign tags = ticket.tags | split: " " %}
{% for tag in tags %}
{% if tag contains "test_" %}
{% assign session = tag | split:" "%}
{% for ses in session %}
{{ses}}
 {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}

Comment: This gives me the filtered test_123 and test_12345 Now I need to parse the test_ and get only highest numeric value.